# Toggling bits pairs in an array to maximize its dot product with another array

Tags: algorithm

Suppose two arrays are given `A` and `B`. `A` consists of integers and the second one consists of 0 and 1.
Now an operation is given - You can choose any adjacent bits in array `B` and you can toggle these two bits (for example - `00->11, 01->10, 10->01, 11->00`) and you can perform this operation any number of times.
The output should be the sum of `A[0]*B[0]+A[1]*B[1]+....+A[N-1]*B[N-1]` such that the sum is maximum.

During the interview, my approach to this problem was to get the maximum number of 1's in array `B` in order to maximize the sum.
So to do that, I first calculated the total number of 1's in O(n) time in `B`. Let count = No. Of 1's=`x`.
Then I started traversing the array and toggle only if count becomes greater than `x` or based on the elements of array `A` (for example: Let `B[i]=0` and `B[i+1]=1` & `A[i]=51` and `A[i+1]=50`
So I will toggle `B[i] B[i+1]` because `A[i]>A[i+1]`)

But the interviewer was not quite satisfied with my approach and was asking me further to develop a less time complex algorithm.

Can anyone suggest a better approach with lesser time complexity?

Comment: are A and B the same size ? Can there be negative numbers in A ?

Comment: Yes, A and B are of the same size. And A can contain negative numbers.

Comment: *"You can choose any adjacent bits in array B"* does it mean that for `B[i]` you can choose to toggle only `B[i + 1]` , or you **have to** toggle `B[i - 1]` too ?

Comment: For B[i] you can choose to toggle only B[i+1].

Comment: Then enable only bits for `A[i] > 0`, this is done in O(n). or maybe I have missed something

Comment: "You can choose any adjacent bits in array B" means that you can either flip B[i-1] and B[i], or B[i] and B[i+1]. You can't just switch B[i] alone

Comment: @Aaron oh okay, thanks

Comment: Your approach is incorrect. eg if A = [10,20,40] and B=[1,1,0], here acc. to your algorithm, maximum dot product will be 50 but actually, it is 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create any B-vector with an even number of flipped bits just by repeatedly flipping the first bit that is in the wrong state.

So, pick all the positive numbers in A, and then drop the smallest one if you ended up with an a count that has a different oddness than the number of 1s in B.  If you can't do that, because B has an odd number of 1s and A is all negative, then just pick the negative number closest to 0.

Then turn on all the bits corresponding to the numbers you chose, and turn off the other ones.

Comment: I feel like you've missed two importants parts of the question : 1) you need to flip values of B in pairs, you can't just set a single element of the array to the value you wish. 2) while I feel like your answer would yield better results than OP's solution, OP's question was about improving performances, and I don't see anything in your answer that would address this.

Comment: 1) That's why you have to flip an even number of bits.  2) the way the OP described his algorithm, it's already fast (linear time), but it's wrong.  This algorithm is linear time and correct.

Comment: Re 1) : I see, I guess I had brushed over your first sentence and didn't realize its implication. I guess it could use some more illustration, but I agree your answer is complete as-is. Re 2) : Right, either the interviewer was unsincere or OP didn't describe his code in details.

Comment: If B initially had odd number of 1 bits, after flipping, we can obtain only (any) odd number of 1 bits. So, your algorithm should be modified for that case.

Comment: @BEWARB, yes, that's why I said "an even number of flipped bits", not "an even number of 1 bits".  The specific handling is in the next sentence.